# How to add where condition to the MongoDB whereObj in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am working on JavaScript with MongoDB.

I have collection name test_collection. It has field/object as test_field_1 , which contains test_sub_field_1 and test_sub_field_2 .

Now, I am putting

```js
var whereObj = {};

var cursor = collection.find(whereObj, {
            '_id': 0
    
        });
```

I tried to use test_sub_field_1 != 34  but it failed. I am trying to put where condition
for test_sub_field_1 != 34 and test_sub_field_1 != 12. In current situation, whereObj is Empty.

```js
var cursor = collection.find(whereObj, {
            '_id': 0,
            'test_field_1.test_sub_field_1': { $ne: 34 }
        });
```

Thanks

Comment: The first argument to [`collection.find()`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/reference/method/db.collection.find/) is the query. You're passing an empty object, so MongoDB will match all documents. What are you intending to do with `whereObj`?

Comment: I am trying to pass where condition to the mongodb query. It should use field test_field_1 which is Object and it contains test_sub_field_1 and test_sub_field_2. Coming from relational db world, my query on where condition is test_field_1.test_sub_field_1 not in ( 34 , 12)

Comment: You should include that as part of the `whereObj`. The second argument is the projection.

Comment: I am trying to include as part of whereObj. But, I am getting syntax error in  test_sub_field_1  .                                                                                    
 ```whereObj = {
                    where: {
                        test_field_1.test_sub_field_1 : { $ne: 34 }
                    }
                }; ```

Answer (score 1):

`find()` in MongoDB takes 3 inputs: **Query**, **Projection** and **Options** (in that order).

You are passing `whereObj` as a Query input (which is empty object). You should change your code like this:

```js
const whereObj = {
  'test_field_1.test_sub_field_1': { $ne: 34 }
};

const cursor = collection.find(whereObj);
```